# What algorithm does mathematica use to compute the Gauss hypergeometric function?

Tags: hypergeometric-function, mathematica, quadrature

I recently tried implementing Gauss Hypergeometric function with c++ in two different ways, but found that they each had some problems in certain parameter regions.

The first way uses the naive series approach and is extremely simple to write:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/255896/

The problem is that this series diverges, e.g., when $x = 1$.

The second way simply calls the function from GNU standard library (GSL), but also encountered [(expected) failure mode](https://github.com/ampl/gsl/blob/master/specfunc/hyperg_2F1.c#L773) for the following set of parameters, discovered by my colleagues:

$a = 1, b = -62.5, c = 2, x \in [0.27^2, 1].$
Curiously, the series approach had no problem with this case.

But [mathematica](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Hypergeometric2F1%281%2C%20-62.5%2C%202%2C%200.27%20*%200.27%29) seems able to handle both cases well:

[image: Wolfram Alpha Screen Shot]

My suspicion is that mathematica uses quadrature method for better numeric stability, though I have no way to verify that. Also is quadrature going to be significantly slower than series methods?

As a bonus, what's a recommended c++ portable implementation to use for 2F1 with the largest possible parameter range? In fact my range is only going to be say $a \in [0, 2]$, $b \in [-100, 0]$, $c \in [0, 5]$ and $x \in [-1, 1]$. My current plan is to simply use the naive series implementation as a backup for GSL, but I am worried there may be points where both fail.

Comment: The [DLMF section 15.19](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.19) has information about the hypergeometric function computation.

Comment: Try https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Hypergeometric2F1%281%2C+-625%2F10%2C+2%2C+%2827%2F100%29%5E2+%29